# I have two arrays with objects inside that I want to compare the values and return the change key value pait and array position

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, state

I want to compare these two arryays and output the key value pairs of the changed value so the out put should be like so only the changed object is in a new array, and if there were other changed objects they would be in order with there changed fields. and I always want the col10 id to be present.

Thanks ahead of time

I have tried the following

```
 oldState.map((item, i) => {
        saveData.map((item1, j) => {
          if (item[`col${i}`] === item1[`col${j}`]) {
            console.log(item1);
          }
        });
      });
```

desired result of comaparison of two arrays

```
[
  {col0:"snappy", col10:"292959180223939085"}
]
```

```
var oldState = 

[
  {
    "col0": "Decor",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "okok",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 7,
    "col5": 5,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fsaf",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615646495/catalog/sse5zxtklsj3ib730zjy.png",
    "col9": 4,
    "col10": "292959180223939085"
  },
  {
    "col0": "Decor",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "fdsafd",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 3,
    "col5": 3,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fdsfsa",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615657360/catalog/qpudbgkrvftjlo5c1yma.png",
    "col9": 5,
    "col10": "292970573359743501"
  }
]
```

```
var saveData = 

[
  {
    "col0": "Snappy",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "okok",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 7,
    "col5": 5,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fsaf",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615646495/catalog/sse5zxtklsj3ib730zjy.png",
    "col9": 4,
    "col10": "292959180223939085"
  },
  {
    "col0": "Decor",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "fdsafd",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 3,
    "col5": 3,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fdsfsa",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615657360/catalog/qpudbgkrvftjlo5c1yma.png",
    "col9": 5,
    "col10": "292970573359743501"
  }
]
```

What i get after trying the answer

[image]

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: I could use the return value of the .map but I wanted to console and test the results first to see if I got the right matches

Comment: you need to declare the variable `for (let key in...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mapped the the `oldState` and `saveData` arrays to return an array `[old, new]` for each pair.
Then created the function to return key and value pair with the different values

Provided both versions of the object have the same keys.

```js
const oldState = [{
    "col0": "Decor",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "okok",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 7,
    "col5": 5,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fsaf",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615646495/catalog/sse5zxtklsj3ib730zjy.png",
    "col9": 4,
    "col10": "292959180223939085"
  },
  {
    "col0": "Decor",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "fdsafd",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 3,
    "col5": 3,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fdsfsa",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615657360/catalog/qpudbgkrvftjlo5c1yma.png",
    "col9": 5,
    "col10": "292970573359743501"
  }
]

const saveData = [{
    "col0": "Snappy",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "okok",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 7,
    "col5": 5,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fsaf",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615646495/catalog/sse5zxtklsj3ib730zjy.png",
    "col9": 4,
    "col10": "292959180223939085"
  },
  {
    "col0": "Decor",
    "col1": "2021-03-31",
    "col2": "fdsafd",
    "col3": true,
    "col4": 3,
    "col5": 3,
    "col6": "Curation",
    "col7": "fdsfsa",
    "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615657360/catalog/qpudbgkrvftjlo5c1yma.png",
    "col9": 5,
    "col10": "292970573359743501"
  }
]

function compareArray(oldItem, newItem) {
  const compared = {};

  for (const key in oldItem) {
    if ((key == 'col10' || oldItem[key] != newItem[key]) && Object.hasOwnProperty.call(newItem, key) && Object.hasOwnProperty.call(oldItem, key)) {
      compared[key] = newItem[key];
    }
  }

  return compared;
}

oldState.map((old, i) => [old, saveData[i]]).forEach((item) => console.log(compareArray(...item)));
```

Comment: weird I get a key is not defined, yet I type it out manually, and then tried copying and pasting to see. I wonder why

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @AndersKitson

Comment: and this is oldItem which it  says key in is not defined `{
  "col0": "Decor",
  "col1": "2021-03-31",
  "col2": "okok",
  "col3": true,
  "col4": 7,
  "col5": 5,
  "col6": "Curation",
  "col7": "fsaf",
  "col8": "https://res.cloudinary.com/kitson-co/image/upload/v1615646495/catalog/sse5zxtklsj3ib730zjy.png",
  "col9": 4,
  "col10": "292959180223939085"
}`

Comment: So it's in the function there is an error? @AndersKitson

Comment: If you're going to recommend `for...in` you need to also provide the appropriate checks for `ownProperty` as otherwise it will iterate all enumerable properties that are keyed by strings including inherited enumerable properties. see: [for...in: Iterating over own properties only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#iterating_over_own_properties_only)

Comment: I added a image above in my post of what I get the oldItem consoles just fine and is a object, so for(key) should work I would think

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the `const` or `let` keyword to declare `key` as a variable. Please look at the changes I made in my answer

Comment: Thanks it's working. Would you know how to also always have col:10 show up with the id associated? as per my original question. Thanks

Comment: Okay, will the `col10` take the value from the `new` or `old` object

Comment: If your interested I posted a new question with mroe details about what I am doing because the issues is not quite solved, but It made more sense to post a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617845/i-need-to-compare-two-arrays-and-have-the-output-be-one-array-objects-being-com